# Exterior Algebra as a quotient is or is not compatible with Exterior Algebra as a vector subspace space with $\det$ convention of wedge product?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, exterior-algebra, graded-algebras

Ok, so I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655899/exterior-algebra-as-a-quotient-is-the-same-as-exterior-algebra-as-a-vector-subsp), but after the first response it quickly devolved into an unfocused mess. I now believe I can adequately formulate my confusion.

Let $V$ be $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$ linear vector space of dimension $n$, and $V^*$ it's dual. I am going to work with the dual space $V^*$ for convenience, but since $(V^*)^*$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$ everything I do here can be done in with $V$ by just replacing vectors with covectors and vice versa. We denote the exterior algebra of $V^*$ by:
$$\Lambda(V^*)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Lambda^k(V^*)$$
where each $\Lambda^k(V)$ is the subspace of multilinear maps $V^k\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ which are totally antisymmetric. The antisymetrization map:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Alt}:(V^*)^{\otimes k}&\longrightarrow \Lambda^k(V^*)
\end{align}
$$
is defined by it's action on a set of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k\in V$:
$$\text{Alt}(\omega)(v_1,\dots,v_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})$$
We define a wedge product on $\Lambda(V^*)$ by:
$$\omega\wedge \eta=\frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}\text{Alt}(\omega\otimes \eta)$$
where $\omega\in \Lambda^k(V^*)$ and $\eta\in \Lambda^k(V^*)$. This product is associative, and turns $\Lambda(V^*)$ into a graded, associative $\mathbb{K}$ algebra with unit element $1\in\mathbb{K}$. Furthermore, one can show that for a set of $k$
covectors $\omega^1,\cdots, \omega^k\in V^*$, the wedge product satisfies:
$$\omega^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^k=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\omega^{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega^{\sigma(k)}$$
I did this proof in edit 3 of my other question, and I would not be surprised if I messed something up. However, even if something is wrong with the proof, I strongly suspect that the above still holds as it seems equivalent to $\textbf{Proposition 14.11 part d)}$ in Lee's smooth manifolds. This property is also why it is called the determinant convention, as if $k=n$, and $\omega^i=e^i$, where $\{e^i\}$ is the basis for $V^*$ dual to the basis $\{e_i\}$ for $V$, then the above product is the determinant of $n$ vectors.

Now, let
$$T(V^*)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty (V^*)^{\otimes n}$$
and let $I$ be the ideal generated by:
$$\{\omega\otimes \omega |\omega\in V^*\}$$
Then since $I$ is a graded ideal, as it is generated by homogenous elements, and $T(V^*)$ is a graded associative $\mathbb{K}$ algebra with unit element $1$, it follows that with
$I_k=I\cap(V^*)^{\otimes k}$:
$$T(V^*)/I=\bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty T(V^*)_k/I_k$$
is a graded associative $\mathbb{K}$ algebra with unit element $1$. Furthermore, it is not hard to show that for $k>n$, $T(V^*)_k/I_k=\{0\}$, and that for $k=0,1$, $T(V^*)_0/I_0=\mathbb{K}$, and $T(V^*)_1/I_1=V^*$. For each $2\leq k\leq n$, we then define the linear map:
$$\phi^k:(V^*)^{\otimes k}\longrightarrow \Lambda^k(V^*)$$
which on simple tensors is given by:
$$\omega^1\otimes\cdots \otimes\omega^k\longrightarrow \omega^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^k$$. The map is easily seen to be surjective, and since any $i\in I_k$ can be written as the sum:
$$i=\sum_i\sum_{j+l=k-2}a_j\otimes(\omega_i\otimes \omega_i)\otimes b_l$$
where each $a_j\in V^{\otimes j}$ and each $b_l\in V^{\otimes l}$, we have that $i\in \ker\phi^k$, so $I_k\subset \ker \phi$, and by the universal property of quotient vector spaces we have that $\phi_k$ descends to a surjective linear map $\psi_k:T(V^*)/I_k\rightarrow \Lambda^k(V^*)$. After deriving some properties of multiplication in $T(V)/I$, which are pretty much the same as the properties of the wedge product, it is also not difficult to see that the set:
$$B=\{[e^{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes e^{i_k}]:i_1<\cdots<i_k\}$$
spans $T(V)_k/I_k$. It is linearly independent since for any linear combination combination:
$$\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}a_{i_1\cdots i_k}[e^{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes e^{i_k}]=0$$
we have that under the map$\psi^k$:
$$\sum_{i_1<\cdots <i_k}a_{i_1\cdots i_k}e^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e^{i_k}=0$$
Hence, if $j_1\cdots j_k$ is any other ordered multi index, we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1<\cdots <i_k}a_{i_1\cdots i_k}e^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e^{i_k}(e_{j_1},\cdots 
e_{j_k})=&\sum_{i_1\cdots i_k}a_{i_1\cdots i_k}\delta^{i_1\cdots i_k}_{j_1\cdots j_k}\\
=&a_{j_1\cdots j_k}\\
=&0
\end{align}
$$
So each coefficient in the sum is zero, and $B$ is linearly independent. Since the size of $B$ is clearly $n$ choose $k$, we have that $\dim T(V^*)_k/I_k=\dim \Lambda^k(V^*)$,
so since $\psi^k$ is surjective, it follows by rank nullity that for each $k$:
$$T(V^*)_k/I_k\cong \Lambda^k(V^*)$$

My question is then this, why can't we use these maps to create an algebra isomorphism between $T(V^*)/I$ and $\Lambda(V^*)$? From the reply in my previous post, it seems to suggest that this is impossible with the wedge product defined as I have it. However, I believe we can. Every element $a\in T(V^*)/I$ can be written as the sum:
$$a=\sum_{i=0}^na_i$$
where each $a_i\in T(V^*)_i/T_i$, hence we use the $\psi^k$'s to define the following map:
$$\psi:\sum_{i=0}^na_i\longrightarrow \sum_{i=0}^n\psi^i(a_i)$$
It is a linear bijection, so as vector spaces we have an isomorphism. By linearity, it suffices to check that one simple products we have that:
$$\psi([\omega^1\otimes\cdots \otimes \omega^k]\cdot [\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^l])=\psi([\omega^1\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k+1}])\wedge \psi([\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k+l}])$$
By the induced multiplicative structure on $T(V)/I$ we have that:
$$[\omega^1\otimes\cdots \otimes \omega^k]\cdot [\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^l]=[\omega^1\otimes \cdots\omega^{k}\otimes\omega^{k+1} \otimes \omega^{k+l}]$$
hence:
$$
\begin{align}
\psi([\omega^1\otimes\cdots \otimes \omega^k]\cdot [\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^l])=&\psi^{k+l}([\omega^1\otimes \cdots\omega^{k}\otimes\omega^{k+1} \otimes \omega^{k+l}])\\
=&\omega^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^k\wedge \omega^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^{k+l}
\end{align}$$
While:
$$
\begin{align}
\psi([\omega^1\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^k])\wedge \psi([\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{l}])=&\psi^k([\omega^1\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^k])\wedge \psi^l([\omega^{k+1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k+l}])\\
=&(\omega^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^{k})\wedge (\omega^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^{k+l})\\
=&\omega^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^k\wedge \omega^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^{k+l}
\end{align}$$
so $\psi$ is respects multiplication in both algebras. It is clear that $\psi(1)=1$, as $\psi^0$ is the identity map, so $\psi$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra homomorphism, and thus an isomorphism.

Am I missing something here? It seems that once we get a vector space isomorphism on each grade everything falls into place.

Comment: I'm writing a longer response that tries to sort out what's really going on here, but I should say that your wedge product is fine; what I meant before is that if we define $$\mathrm{alt}_0(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k) = \sum_{\sigma\in S^k}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$$ then the product $$X\wedge Y := \mathrm{alt}_0(X\otimes Y) $$ is non-associative on alternating tensors $X,Y$. What I meant is you need to have a normalization factor *somewhere*, and when I wrote my answer you hadn't yet clarified your definitions/conventions.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I see that makes sense.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff does this also mean that my algebra isomorphism works ? Or is there another issue I’m not seeing

Comment: Yes, it is an isomorphism. It's actually a *different* isomorphism from the one I showed: your isomorphism gives the correspondence $$[v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k] \leftrightarrow \mathrm{alt}_0(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k),$$ whereas mine gives $$[v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k] \leftrightarrow \color{red}{\frac1{k!}}\mathrm{alt}_0(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k). $$

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Ok great thank you, that also kind of makes sense. If you have the time though, I would love to see your response which sorts all this out. If not, no worries.

Comment: @Chris -- I wrote an answer to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770978/1155637 which might be useful to look at. In particular, I think it is useful to try to view at the exterior algebra and the algebra of alternating forms as dual constructions and then relate them using $V^{**} = V$ in the finite-dimensional setting. The Lemma at the end of the answer might also be helpful.